# Simultaneous matrix transpose for large array of matrices

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, transpose

I have an image with dimensions `rows x cols x deps`. In every voxel of this image, there is a 3x3 matrix, hence the shape of my numpy array is: `(rows, cols, deps, 3, 3)`.

I know that I can simultaneously invert all these matrices using the gufunced version of `numpy.linalg.inv()`; which is pretty awesome.

However, how can I simultaneously transpose all the 3x3 matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`swapaxes` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) to swap the last two dimensions:

```
In [17]: x = np.random.randint(0, 99, (4,4,4,3,3))

In [18]: x[0,0,0]
Out[18]: 
array([[21, 93, 83],
       [57,  0, 96],
       [43, 37, 22]])

In [19]: x[1,1,2]
Out[19]: 
array([[59,  0, 27],
       [85, 97, 19],
       [91, 52, 68]])

In [20]: y = x.swapaxes(-1,-2)

In [21]: y[0,0,0]
Out[21]: 
array([[21, 57, 43],
       [93,  0, 37],
       [83, 96, 22]])

In [22]: y[1,1,2]
Out[22]: 
array([[59, 85, 91],
       [ 0, 97, 52],
       [27, 19, 68]])
```

Comment: Note that this will only change the view of the data.  If you need to actually rearrange the data in memory, you would have to make a copy.

Comment: Thanks Warren, I think that should work for me. I'll double check it in and accept if it works out.